# Gpload is slow when called in a nested function

Tags: java, python, talend, greenplum

We have a talend job (generates Java code) that calls gpload via the following way:

```
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
      Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
      final Process ps = rt.exec(cmds, envp);
    }
}
```

My problem is that when we call it from our job there are 6-8 nested functions prior to executing this.

The Python program execution time is 13-16 minutes.

However If I call it in a separate job, without any nested loops, it executes in 1.5 - 2 minutes.

```
Not good
2014-09-11 06:31:40|LOG|INSERT INTO "sh_pbprodlib"."f0101" 
2014-09-11 06:44:31|INFO|running time: 771.98 seconds
Good
2014-09-11 10:06:48|LOG|INSERT INTO "sh_pbprodlib"."f0101"
2014-09-11 10:08:43|INFO|running time: 115.23 seconds
```

I've also executed gpload command from Linux shell while the 15 minute job ran, and its execution time was around 1.5 minutes.

How can I overcome on this behaviour?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: My question is: Why is this happening? What should I do to overcome on this behaviour? Today we load a table that had 2 rows under 123seconds, which is not good.

Comment: First, activate the logging of statement execution time by running this: `gpconfig -c log_duration -v on`. Next, attach the pg_log for the loading sessions (filter eveything on gp_session_id for the session loaded the data)